# A closed question on GIS is again closed and deleted here

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, deleted-questions

Yesterday, I asked a question on [GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62116/mapping-data-to-graphical-three-ways-of-representing-objects) about visualization and needed some examples to understand a paragraph of a book better. People commented that it has nothing to do with GIS and you better ask it on [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60512/mapping-data-to-graphical-three-ways-of-representing-objects) and a moderator closed as a duplicate of a completely irrelevant question. Since I've got no answer to my question, I asked it on cross validated as well, since people suggested so. Again, the above mentioned moderator came and closed my question as not constructive and deleted  it (they commented  it is cross-posted even though I mentioned it in the body of the question). I have no idea why people behaved naively and why I have nowhere to get satisfying answers to my questions. This is very disappointing and it's the first time I've encountered such behaviors especially from the ones who are elected to moderate the community. Stack exchange has been my most reliable to source to solve my problems and answer my questions in about a year.

Answer (score 5):

As the above-mentioned moderator, I have fully explained the reasons for closing the question both times. The first time was *not* that it was off topic: as the link plainly shows, it was closed as a duplicate. You subsequently commented that you did not see how the duplicate was a duplicate--without further explanation--and I replied pointing out how it was. I am sorry that you are disappointed with the outcome, but shopping a question from one SE site to the other without addressing the issues raised is not likely to be successful.

In this case, one option (still) open to you is to flag the original question for migration. A better one is to consider seriously the reasons for closing it and address them first by editing the question to make it conform to SE guidelines.  (Comments on both the GIS site and this one all point to significant deficiencies that would prevent it staying open for many reasons.)

One option that will not work on SE is to make public *ad hominem* allegations or insinuations (as in your use of "naively"): that only incites the community to react negatively to *you,* as the violator of the site norms of discourse, and may limit its ability to consider your *question* seriously.  Although it's not easy to alienate moderators--we're used to much worse--it's a better idea to engage our support instead.

---

By the way, you haven't actually asked a question here, so if you do not edit it soon to actually ask one, the community will soon close *this* thread, too.

Comment: I really don't care whether it's closed or open, just wanted to state my opinion somewhere. I am an old user of different SE sites, so I know how to ask questions here and there. cross-posting is allowed if the one mention they've asked it before with a link to it. Thank you anyway!

Comment: (After much deliberation!) I guess you're right. I should of improved the question instead. I asked it again because people suggested it's better suited here. I apologize if I sounded churlish.

Comment: No problem--as I said, mods are daily subjected to worse. You have distinguished yourself (in a positive way) by acknowledging our mutual responsibility for the fate of your question. I would be glad to continue to help you improve it into something that is on-topic at one of the SE sites.